# Query for status change on particular day

Tags: eclipse, rtc, jazz

How do I write a query which will allow me to me view all the work items changed to a particular state on a particular day?

Example, we have a status field which developers change from "In Progress" to  "Retest Ready".

I'd like a query which will return me all the work items which changed from "In Progress" to  "Retest Ready" on a given day.

Comment: Talking to the RTC guys it appears this is a limitation of RTC at ATM.